# Difference between dense set and everywhere dense set

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I'd like to know what is the main difference between these definitions? In functional analysis we can face everywhere dense set but there is no the same definition in topology. In Engelking "General topology" we have only dense, dense-in-itself and nowhere dense set. I'm just a little bit confused about definitions.

Comment: It would help if you include the two definitions in your post.

Comment: [Kolmogorov](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Auteurs/Kolmogorov/Introductory%20Real%20Analysis%20-%20Kolmogorov%20Fomin(1).pdf) page 48 p.6.3

A is said to be the everywhere dense (in R) if [A] = R 
 and if we talk about topological definition I prefer using GENERAL TOPOLOGY, BY RYSZARD ENGELKING
A set A \subset X is called dense in X if cl(A) = X

As for me it is called practically the same

As a main characteristic of the everywhere dense set is :
R is everywhere dense in itself and dense (not everywhere) in (0; 1)

Comment: What does  $[A]$ mean?

Comment: Can you give a specific reference to a use of the term "everywhere dense" is causing you trouble? In my experience, "everywhere dense" is occasionally used as a synonym for "dense".

Comment: @RobArthan , Kolmogorov uses a bit different definition of the "dense" set. He says:  "Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of a metric space R. Then A is said to be dense in B if $[A] \supset B$. In particular, $A$ is said to be everywhere dense (in $R$) if $[A] = R$."

Comment: But it seems that Kolmogorov uses everyehere dense set in order that today we use dense set. I mean that today we don't neet to re-define everywhere dense set we use dense set as usual.

Comment: @guest. I see. In a way Kolmogorov'# terminology is better than the usual modern usage of "dense", which is implicit about  the ambient space.

Answer (score 2):

For a set $A \subseteq X$, a space:

1. dense = everywhere dense $\iff$ the closure of $A$ is $X$ $\iff$ every non-empty open subset of $X$ intersects $A$.
2. dense-in-itself means that $A$ has no isolated points in its subspace topology $\iff$ There is no open subset $O$ of $X$ so that $|O \cap A|=1$ $\iff$ $A \subseteq A'$ (where the latter is the set of limit points of $A$, the so-called derived set).
3. nowhere dense means there is no non-empty open set $O$ so that $O \subseteq \overline{A}$ $\iff$ there is no non-empty open set $O$ so that $O \cap A$ is dense in $O$ (this explains the name; in classic parlance "nowhere" meant "inside no non-empty open set"). There are several other equivalences I won't bore you with.

But usually everywhere dense is an old-fashioned synonym for what is just "dense" so the definition under 1.

Kolmogorov's definition of $A$ is dense in $B$ is just saying that $A \cap B$ is dense in $B$ in its subspace topology, by standard facts on the closure. Or more intuitively: we can approximate points of $B$ arbitrarily closely by points of $A$. "everywhere dense" is just emphasising that we can do this for all points of $X$ now.

Comment: From the comments under the post it seems, that the confusion comes from a bit different definition of a "dense set" in the Kolmogorov's book. He says:  "Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of a metric space $R$. Then $A$ is said to be dense in $B$ if $[A] \supset B$. In particular, $A$ is said to be everywhere dense (in $R$) if $[A] = R$."